# How can I make something happen x percentage?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to write a piece of code in the form of c*b, where c and b are random numbers and the product is smaller than INT_MAx. But b or c has to be equal to 0 10% of the time and I don't know how to do that.

```
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int product = b*c;

    c = rand() % 10000;
    b = rand()  % INT_MAX/c;
            b*c < INT_MAX;

    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout << "What is " << c << "x" << b << "?"<<endl;
            cin >> guess;
```

Comment: Stuff to read: https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/probability/damage-rolls.html , http://www.sniff.org.uk/2015/11/the-generation-of-random-numbers-is-too.html?m=1 and please *don't ever* use `srand`/`random`. They generate horribly bad random numbers. Use the facilities in the [random header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: `srand ( time(NULL) );` - except for a hard coded seed, that's probably in the top 10 of "worst seed ever".

Comment: Explore the specification: Do you basically mean "b is zero 5% of the time and c is zero 5% of the time"? Or could we have "c is zero 10% of the time, and b is never zero"? Do you ever want b and c to both be zero? I assume whoever set this challenge told you what random number generator to use? Or has explained how poor `rand()` is?

Comment: We have to use a random generator, and rand is given as an example. the product of b and c has to be 0 10% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [std::piecewise_constant_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution)

```
 std::random_device rd; 
 std::mt19937 gen(rd());
 double interval[] = {0, 0, 1, Max};
 double weights[] = { .10, 0, .9};     
 std::piecewise_constant_distribution<> dist(std::begin(interval),
                                             std::end(interval),
                                             weights);
 dist(gen);
```

Answer (score 1):

An int is always less than or equal to INT_MAX therefore you can simply multiply a random boolean variable that is true with 90% probability with the product of two uniformly distributed integers:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 generator(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform;
std::bernoulli_distribution bernoulli(0.9); // 90% 1 ; 10% 0
const int product = bernoulli(generator) * uniform(generator) * uniform(generator)
```

If you had a specific limit in mind, like say N for the individual numbers and M for the product of the two numbers you can do:

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform(0,N);
std::bernoulli_distribution bernoulli(0.9); // 90% 1 ; 10% 0
int product;
do { product = bernoulli(generator) * uniform(generator) * uniform(generator) }
while(!(product<M));
```

edit: std::piecewise_constant_distribution is more elegant, didn't know about it until I read the other answer.

Comment: `std::default_random_engine` - why? That is, in my book, always the wrong choice. You don't know what you get (which *may* be a horrible linear-congruential generator). Name the engine you *want* explicitly. `std::default_random_engine` should not exist IMO and should definitely *never* be used.

Comment: You should see std::default_random_engine as a stand-in. This is just an example to a question on how to generate random numbers with a given property, not an answer to which random number generator is superior. For many use cases a linear congruential generator is good enough.

Comment: If it's just a "stand in", then why not just use "std::mt19937" for that purpose? As a "stand in" it's equally good and if someone actually copies and uses the code without understanding it (likely) it will give them better results.

Comment: kk I changed it, you're right. I made a test and with some bad luck you can actually run into the problem of generating to few uneven numbers because either (i*c+a)%m or ((i+1)*c+a)%m is even. I had thought that multiplying two (even hardly) random numbers would make things very chaotic, but in this case, probably because everything is linear, not for the lowest bit(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a portable solution that does not depend on the standard C++ library and also which is faster, and maybe simpler to understand, you can use the following snippet. The variable `random_sequence` is a pre-generated array of random numbers where the 0 happens 10% of the time. The variable `runs` and `len` are used to index into this array as an endless sequence. This is however, a simple solution, since the pattern will repeat after 90 runs. But if you don't care about the pattern repeating then this method will work fine.

```
int runs = 0;
int len = 90; //The length of the random sequence.
int random_sequence[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

int coefficient = random_sequence[runs % len];
runs++;
```

Then, whatever variable you want to be 0 10% of the time you do it like this:

```
float b = coefficient * rand();
```

or

```
float c = coefficient * rand();
```

If you want both variables to be 0 10% of the times individidually then it's like this:

```
float b = coefficient * rand();
coefficient = random_sequence[runs % len];
float c = coefficient * rand();
```

And if you want them to be 0 10% of the times jointly then the `random_sequence` array must be like this:

```
int len = 80;
int random_sequence[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

And use

```
float b = coefficient * rand();
float c = coefficient * rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a shot here @[ http://codepad.org/DLbVfNVQ ]. Average value is somewhere in the neighborhood of 0.4. -CR